# how to run script in brackets extension package.json?

Tags: node.js, package.json, adobe-brackets

I want run script in Brackets Extension manager when install my extension.

Found this code in Brackets default Extension 'JavaScriptCodeHints'.

```
{
  "name": "brackets-javascript-code-hints",
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "3.3.0",
    "tern": "0.20.0"
},
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./fix-acorn"
  }
}
```

same using "postinstall": "node ./test", but displayed this error message.

```
npm-stderr: sh: node: command not found

npm WARN testExtensionInstaller@1.0.1 No description
npm WARN testExtensionInstaller@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN testExtensionInstaller@1.0.1 No license field.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS/Brackets-node" "/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/www/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! testExtensionInstaller@1.0.1 postinstall: `node ./test`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the testExtensionInstaller@1.0.1 postinstall script 'node ./test'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the testExtensionInstaller package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./test
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs testExtensionInstaller
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls testExtensionInstaller
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/1y/bd63w8h51wzccq_zbw6804440000gn/T/bracketsPackage_117723-46419-zgk6x5.ki3sicc8fr/testExtensionInstaller/npm-debug.log
```

how using node without install nodejs in Brackets extension install?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with brackets, you need to update the filesystem path to include node

You need to Add the place where you installed nodeJS something like (`C:\Program Files\nodejs`) to your PATH environment variable. To do this follow these steps:

1. Use the global Search Charm to search "Environment Variables"
2. Click "Edit system environment variables"
3. Click "Environment Variables" in the dialog.
4. In the "System Variables" box, search for Path and edit it to include `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. Make sure it is separated from any other paths by a `;`.

You will have to restart any currently-opened command prompts before it will take effect.

Comment: I khow that. but default extension installed in without nodejs and PATH environment.

Comment: Please check if node's path is inside brackets-nodejs' runtime environment by executing following file using the extension: `console.log(process.env.PATH);`

Comment: it's default extension, so installed with Brackets(Internal extension). so i can't add code until build bracket. https://github.com/adobe/brackets/tree/master/src/extensions/default/JavaScriptCodeHints is default extension github url

Comment: i was reading the issues, some suggested to `delete Brackets completely and reinstall Brackets via the latest installer again.`

Comment: I do not speak English well, so it seems that the intention has been misunderstood.
I want to develop an extension in which the node runs in the script like package.json in the default extension. The default extension is installed correctly, but in my extension there is an error that the node can not be found.